# Why "Take something with [reflexive pronoun]" is incorrect?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, phrasal-verbs, reflexive-pronouns

People don't use bring/take/etc *(If you know other similar verbs, please tell me)* with reflexive pronouns. I heard that from one of my English teachers too. Why?

> As I know we need to use objective pronouns after those phrasal verbs/verbs.

- Take it with yourself [Incorrect]
- Take it with you [Correct]

[Edited]

- You need to take it out with yourself [Incorrect].
- You need to be on good terms with yourself [Correct].

Answer (score 1):

Your English teacher is right that "Take it with yourself." isn't idiomatic.

But I don't think it is because of the verbs "take" and "bring", because we can say:

> "**Take** one for your**self** too if you want."
>
> "We nearly **brought** our**selves** to tears with our sad stories."
>
> "I can **bring** it my**self**."

It may be that it is the preposition "with" that causes the reflexive (-self) pronoun to sound "wrong". Here are a couple of examples using other verbs and "with":

> "I still keep his photograph **with me**." (not "my**self**")
>
> "Carry this **with you** at all times." (not "with
>   your**self**")

But on the other hand,

> "I don't have my passport on me."
>
> "I still see that terrible image before me."

Neither of those sounds right with "my**self**", and they don't contain "bring"/"take" *or* "with".

My conclusion is that it is the concepts being discussed, and not any of the individual words, that cause the reflexive pronoun to be appropriate or not.

The only examples I could think of (where we can't use a reflexive pronoun) do involve the idea of accompaniment or possessing/having something near. Perhaps in English that is a concept that doesn't permit a reflexive pronoun. (?)

Yours is an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the reflexive pronoun, but the pronoun along with "with" that is not so used.

> - You want wine at the party? Then bring it yourself.
> - I am not hauling the table for him. He needs to take it himself.

The above and many similar constructions are valid and perfectly natural speech. But i can't think of many cases where "with yourself" would be a likely and natural usage, and none with verbs such as "bring" or "take". One could say:

> - You need to be on good terms with yourself.
> - You should spend some time alone with yourself.

But those are very different constructions.

Comment: I'm talking about "to take" and "to bring" and etc. What you said is different as you said that yourself! The verb is a "to be" verb with a preposition. I don't understand why we can not say: you need to take it out with yourself! It's incorrect!